# Compact operator in Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

$H$ is a Hilbert space and $A$ is a bounded operator on $H$. If $A^*A$ is compact, is it necessarily that $A$ is compact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If $A^\ast A$ is compact, then its positive square root $|A|=(A^\ast A)^{1/2}$ is also compact. Then one can consider the polar decomposition of $A$,
\begin{equation}
A = U|A|,
\end{equation}
where $U$ is a partial isometry. Since the compact operators form an ideal in $B(H)$, it follows that $A$ is compact as well.